# Why doesn't this simple, one line javascript code work?

Tags: javascript

using google chrome, i don't know why this doesn't work :(

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      http://*/*
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementsByTagName('a').style.color='Red';
```

Comment: Btw, CSS color names are usually written in lowercase (e.g. `'red'`).

Answer (score 4):

Because it returns an *"array-like"* collection of elements that you need to operate on individually.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.color='red';
```

---

If you anticipate multiple matches, you'd operate in a loop.

```
var aList = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = aList.length; i < len; i++) {
    aList[i].style.color='red';
}
```

---

Of course for this simple operation, you'd probably use CSS instead of JS.

If you only want links, you can use `document.links` instead of `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList).  You'd have to do something like the following:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), i, j;
for (i=0, j=anchors.length; i<j; i++) {
    anchors[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `for-in` on Arrays or Array-like collections. Your current code will throw an error in Firefox because non-elements are included in the `for-in` loop.

Comment: Your for-in loop will also catch the `'length'`, `'item'`, and `'namedItem'` properties of the NodeList. Avoid for-in. Use for instead.

Comment: @user1689607 Yes sir, you are correct. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList), not just one element.  You need to loop through and edit each one's `style.color`.

Comment: i changed it to this 
for(int i = 0; i<document.getElementsByTagName('a').length; i++){
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].style.color='Red';
}
and it is still not working

Comment: @user1757372: Assign `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` to a variable, don't keep calling it.

Comment: var x = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(int i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
document.x[i].style.color='Red';
}

still nothing..

Comment: @user1757372: It's `x`, not `document.x`.

Comment: @user1757372: It's `var i = 0`, not `int i = 0`.

Comment: @user1757372: your code isn't valid JavaScript. There's no `int` designation for variables